# how do I solve this error in python (code in Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, codexl

I created this program in march and it worked fine then, but now it has an error and I can't figure out why.
[image: the error it shows]
[image: how it looked when it was working]

here is the current non working code (I coded this on Jupiter notebook)

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import seaborn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'


df = yf.download("spy")
df.to_csv('spy.csv')
df = df[['Adj Close']]
plt.plot(df)

df['Adj Close'].plot(figsize=(15,6), color = 'g')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()


forecast = 70
df['Prediction'] = df[['Adj Close']].shift(-forecast)
X = np.array(df.drop(['Prediction'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)            
X_forecast = X[-forecast:]
X = X[:-forecast]
y = np.array(df['Prediction'])
y = y[:-forecast]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
confidence
forecast_predicted = clf.predict(X_forecast)
print(forecast_predicted)

plt.plot(X, y)

dates = pd.date_range(start="2021-05-21", end= "2021-06-19")
plt.plot(dates, forecast_predicted, color='b')
df['Adj Close'].plot(color='g')
plt.xlim(xmin = datetime.date(2020,5,1))
plt.xlim(xmax = datetime.date(2021,7,1))
```

I know the error is in the last part of the code.
here is how the last part of the code looked when it was working on march 15.

```
dates = pd.date_range(start="2021-03-16", end= "2021-04-14")
plt.plot(dates, forecast_predicted, color='b')
df['Adj Close'].plot(color='g')
plt.xlim(xmin = datetime.date(2020,3,1))
plt.xlim(xmax = datetime.date(2021,5,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in the error output: yours x and y first dimensions don't match. The problem is you are forecasting for 70 days (forecast=70) and trying to plot that onto 30 days period.

You can either try changing forecast days:

```
forecast=30
```

Or the time period so it matches 70 days, something like this:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start="2021-05-21", end= "2021-07-29")
```